# Netbeans - how do I find the path to a file within this IDE?

Tags: java, file, plugins, netbeans, path

I want to be able to right click an item within the 'Projects' or 'Files' window, and either have an 'open in file system' option, or 'copy absolute path to this file'.

Is there a plugin or a hidden option within Netbeans that will allow me to achieve this?

I just need an easier way to get to the folder within Windows Explorer without having to spend the time navigating there.

I'm open to making a small plugin myself if it'll make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a community contributed plugin on [NetBeans bug-tracking system](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=153728) that can implement the feature. I have verified that the plugin works well with NetBeans 6.9.1. Once installed, you could copy the path of a file (or files under a folder node) via Edit/Copy Path menu.

[Plugin "Path Tools" @ plugins.netbeans.org](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=676)

Comment: Thanks Wen Q., this is precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 17):

With Netbeans 8 you can use:

```
Alt+Shift+L
```

It's defined under Options->Keymap as Copy File Path(s)

Comment: You can find it under Netbeans->Preferences->Keymap on OSx with Netbeans 8.0.2

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat related : [netbeans - how to view file full path in window title (or somewhere else)?](https://superuser.com/questions/88637/netbeans-how-to-view-file-full-path-in-window-title-or-somewhere-else)
You can use either of following :

> 1. Use Alt+Shift+O to open files by name (which shows the path and the
>      project)
> 2. Hit Ctrl+Shift+1 while in the editor to highlight the file in the
>      Projects View

Answer (score 1):

I use this plugin which lets you copy the full path of a file to the clipboard - https://github.com/kinkadzs/QuickOpener-NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

The information you search can be accessed trough the file properties.

In the Projects window, right click on a file, select 'Properties', the file path is under the 'All Files' line.

You can also press Alt-Shift-O while the file is selected in the Projects view or the file you're editing.

Comment: But one can't copy it from there…